# How to show active version on wordpress.org of a published plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, svn, readme

I have published a plugin, first time, on wordpress.org.
The problem I have is that it doesn't show the stats of `active version` and only option for download is a `Development Version`.

My svn structure is,

`/assets/` (plugin image assets)
`/branches/`(empty)
`/tags/2.3.0/`(plugin files)
`/trunk/`(plugin files)

**Note**: For Development purposes and version control, the initial version of the plugin is 2.3.0 and its the same as in the `trunk` folder.

The readme file of the plugin:

```
===  XXXXX ===
Contributors:   
Donate link: 
Tags:
Requires at least: 3.0.1
Tested up to: 4.7.3
Stable tag: 2.3.0
License: GPLv2

== Description ==

= Requirements =

= Documentation & Support =

== Installation ==

= Usage =

== Screenshots ==



== Upgrade Notice ==
*

== Changelog ==

= 2.3.0 2017.02.16 =
*

== Frequently Asked Questions ==
```

I have removed the name of the plugin as well as the redundant parts.
This `readme.txt` is validated from the WordPress readme validatior.

Answer (score 1):

For the current version, make sure you include the Version attribute in your plugin header file. Like this:

```
/*
Plugin Name: WordPress.org Plugin
Plugin URI:  https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/
Description: Basic WordPress Plugin Header Comment
Version:     2.3.0
Author:      WordPress.org
Author URI:  https://developer.wordpress.org/
License:     GPL2
License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: wporg
Domain Path: /languages
*/
```

For more detail check the [WordPress Header Requirements documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/header-requirements/).